# Whats wrong with this angular code?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS. Trying to learn from a tutorial on youtube. I write the same code what trainer wrote. But unfortunately my one is not working. I apologize for sharing this type of silly problem but I'm really astonished to see that same code is not working for me. Thanks in advance.

```
<body data-ng-app="">
<div data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
    <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="cust in Customers">
            {{cust.Name}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script src="../Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script>
    function SimpleController($scope) {
        $scope.Customers = [
            { Name: "Chanchal", City: "Dhaka" },
            { Name: "Masud", City: "Jessore" },
            { Name: "Humayun", City: "Barisal" }
        ];
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Do you see any error(s) in your developer console?

Comment: Does the angular.js library is loaded ? Can you confirm you don't have ang console errors?

Comment: what is name of your ngapp and please post what errors you are getting in console window

Comment: I'm getting the following error- angular.js:14110 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'SimpleController' is not a function, got undefined

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27960365/error-ngareq-argument-simplecontroller-is-not-a-function-got-undefined

Comment: I put it in head tag but nothing changed. @A.T.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if you are using angular version below 1.3 , check here

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script  src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0/angular.js"></script>
</head>

<body data-ng-app>
  <div data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
    <ul>
      <li data-ng-repeat="cust in Customers">
        {{cust.Name}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
 
<script>

function SimpleController($scope) { $scope.Customers = [ { Name: "Chanchal", City: "Dhaka" }, { Name: "Masud", City: "Jessore" }, { Name: "Humayun", City: "Barisal" } ]; }
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. The problem was with my version. Thanks a lot

Comment: i used 1.4 and its worked....http://plnkr.co/edit/kqkWKqNFfIBLLIlwYQVE?p=preview....but i am confuse with your workds "It should work if you are using angular version below 1.3"...can u explain this

Comment: in your sample you have defined the controller in separate file and its not global, that s the difference

Answer (score 0):

You have to bootstrap angular app.

> var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

```
<script>
  var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

  function SimpleController($scope) {
    $scope.Customers = [
        { Name: "Chanchal", City: "Dhaka" },
        { Name: "Masud", City: "Jessore" },
        { Name: "Humayun", City: "Barisal" }
    ];
  }
</script>
```

And

```
<body data-ng-app="myApp">
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nitishkumarsingh13/Lvc0u55v/13100/)

Comment: He also needs to register the controller.

Comment: But I want to use this controller without using module. Isn't it possoble?

Comment: @norbertk No. he can use without register controller.

Comment: It depends on which version he's using. After angular 1.3, it does not discover globally defined controllers.

Answer (score 0):

you can't have global controllers in angular, (except if you allow global controllers using `controllerProvider`)

```
 function SimpleController($scope) {
        $scope.Customers = [
            { Name: "Chanchal", City: "Dhaka" },
            { Name: "Masud", City: "Jessore" },
            { Name: "Humayun", City: "Barisal" }
        ];
    }

SimpleController.$inject = ['$scope'];
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('SimpleController', SimpleController);
```

and in HTML,

```
<body  ng-app="myApp">
```

Comment: This won't work as since 1.3.0+ angular will no longer look for globally defined controllers

Comment: @A.T. Your code is working  fine but I want to do it in the way I tried. Actually I need to know whats wrong with it.

Comment: @ChanchalZoarder which version of angular you are using at the moment ?