# AngularJS: Argument 'Ctrl' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm learning AngularJS and have come across this error while implementing a controller.

Can someone point out what's wrong? (followed this exactly as it's shown in a tutorial unless some of the functions are deprecated?)

I get the following error:
`Argument 'Ctrl' is not a function, got undefined`

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>AngularJS Controller</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js">   </script>

</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <input ng-model="name">
    <input ng-model="age">
    <h1>{{ name }}</h1>
    <h1>{{ age }}</h1>
</div>

<script>
    var Ctrl = function($scope) {
        $scope.name = "Noob";
        $scope.age = "21";
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19408011/angularjs-error-argument-firstctrl-is-not-a-function-got-undefined?rq=1

Comment: Do they still support that *"function as controller"* stuff in 1.3? Maybe try using the full `angular.module(...).controller(function($scope) { ... })` thing. Also, you're missing the `$scope` argument

Comment: Exactly: the old method of defining controllers as global functions is deprecated, one must opt in to use it ([see controllerProvider.allowGlobals()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$controllerProvider)). Do what Phil suggests.

Comment: You have to pass $scope to ctrl function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I know you need to define controller using module.controller method. For example, name your app as myApp

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
```

and the js part will be:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.name = "Noob";
        $scope.age = "21";
    }]);
```

Comment: Yes, I agree. It's not required

Comment: Thanks. This works, tried all the other solutions and still had the same errors.

Comment: Sorry, this **is** required in 1.3 unless you set `allowGlobals` on the `controllerProvider` as mentioned above in the comments

Comment: That `$scope.name` though. XD

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your app

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
```

and pass $scope into your controller

```
var Ctrl = function($scope) {
```

Here's a fiddle link with those changes: http://jsfiddle.net/fxk7mtb7/

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate? Because when do those things, it works: http://jsfiddle.net/fxk7mtb7/

Comment: Have tried your solution and still get the same error, even though it works on JSFiddle.

Comment: I made the same mistake in my JSFiddle and used Angular 1.2. Here it is (broken) in 1.3 - http://jsfiddle.net/fxk7mtb7/1/

Comment: Invalid since [AngularJS 1.3.0-beta.15](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/3f2232b5a181512fac23775b1df4a6ebda67d018).