# Data not showing with angular $http service by using php?

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

im building a project with angular,i have a html form that sends data to "customers" table in MYSQL. now i want to show the data of "customers" table. this is my code that i tried to get that data but its not working. can anyone help?

php code:

```
<?php
  $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','hamatkin');
  if(!$con){
    die("couldnt connect".mysqli_error);
  }
  $query = "SELECT * FROM customers";
  $result = $con->query($query);
  $r = array();
  if( $result->num_rows>0){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
      $r[] = $row;
    }
  }
  $res = json_encode($r);
  echo $res;
  echo $sql_statement;
  ?>
```

controller:

```
"use strict";
var app = angular.module('dataSystem',[]);
app.controller('customerCardsCtrl',function($scope,$route,$location,$http){
    $http({method:'GET', url:'api/get-allCustomers.php'}).success(function(response){
        $scope.customers = response.data;
      });
    });
});
```

html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>


    <div>
      <table ng-controller="customerCardsCtrl" >
        <tr ng-repeat="x in customers">
        <td> {{ x.customer_id}} </td>
        <td>{{ x.first_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ x.last_name }}</td>
        <td> {{ x.id}} </td>
        <td> {{ x.city}} </td>
        <td> {{ x.adress}} </td>
        <td> {{ x.phone}} </td>
        <td> {{ x.email}} </td>
        <td> {{ x.fax}} </td>
        <td> {{ x.referrer}} </td>
        <td> {{ x.comments}} </td>

        </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what error you are facing?

Comment: the html page is not showing data and remains the same

Comment: you print 2 json in php side. please remove 1 which is not correct.

Comment: `phpMyAdmin` is a tool written in PHP `MYSQL` is a DBMS

Comment: can u be more specific?

Comment: @DennisKapitankin what is an error ?

Comment: Using the javascript debugger find out what is on `response`

Comment: the console is showing me this errors
script1002: syntax error customerCardsCtrl.js(22,5) 
     
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'customerCardsCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19408011/angularjs-error-argument-firstctrl-is-not-a-function-got-undefined looks like this is more an angular issue, which is not my strongpoint

Comment: Your PHP does not produce valid JSON format string due to ` echo $res;
  echo $sql_statement;` just remove them.

Comment: i removed what u said....stil the same ...

Answer (score 0):

use this code instead

```
"use strict";
var app = angular.module('dataSystem',[]);
app.controller('customerCardsCtrl',function($scope,$route,$location,$http){
  $http({method:'GET', url:'api/get-allCustomers.php'})
    .then(function(response){
           $scope.customers = response.data;
       }, function(response){
           console.log(response)
       });
});
```

Comment: the console showing me: warning tried to load angular more than once,                              and: script1002: syntax error customerCardsCtrl.js(8,1),                                        and: error: [ng:areq] argument 'customerCardsCtrl' is not a function got undefined

Comment: did you remove that extra }); you added?

Comment: i have to leave the extra }): because without it the page isn't working

Comment: the rest of your code is ok except that you must remove **echo $sql_statement;** in your php code. please try the edited controller code

Comment: i removed echo_$sql statement, and i tried the edited code but the code makes the pages not to work , thats why i have to do an extra }); and then the page working great except not showing details from table "customers". but thanks for trying to help ! can u try to help in another program?(skype,teamviewer, chrome remote desktop)

Comment: Yes, sure.  Dennis can you please share your Skype details