# AngularJS error: 'argument 'MapCtrl' is not a function, got undefined'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, frameworks

**Controllers.js**
 angular.module('starter.controllers',[])

```
.controller('AppCtrl',function($scope,$rootScope) {
    $rootScope.side_menu = document.getElementsByTagName("ion-side-menu")[0];

 $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, toState, toParams, fromParams, toParams) {
if (toState.name != 'app.map') {
    $rootScope.side_menu.style.visibility = "visible";
}
});
})
.controller('MapCtrl',function($scope) {
    $rootScope.side_menu.style.visibility = "hidden";
})
```

New to Angular and Ionic. Have already checked out the other questions regarding this error. Thanks.

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LjKt.jpg)

[AppJS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRcd5.jpg)

Comment: Will you also paste in your html

Comment: why are you calling your module `starter.controllers` when you use `ng-app="Starter"`

Comment: I can remove that?

Comment: I believe it is confused regarding which module you ar adding the controller to. Add angular.module('starter.controllers',[]) in front of your second controller or save it in a var and add it in front of every subsequent controller you will use for this module.

Comment: I would call your module this `angular.module('starter',[])` I dont know if that is your problem but the `ng-app` directive needs to match ***Letter for letter*** whatever you call your app

Comment: @ZabedAkbar he doesnt need to do that, he is chaining the controllers so that isnt necessary

Comment: Something wrong with your angular module declaration. Check out the following thread 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19408011/angularjs-error-argument-firstctrl-is-not-a-function-got-undefined

Comment: I also have an app.js file. Will it be relevant for this case?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `;` in **app.js** from the name of the controller MapCtrl.

**'MapCtrl;'** should be **'MapCtrl'** like in example

```
    .state('app.map,{
      url:"/map",
      views: {
      'menuContent' :{
      templateUrl: "templates/map.html",
      controller: 'MapCtrl'
      }
     }
    })
```

P.S. After that you should inject `$rootScope` inside MapCtrl because otherwise you'll get `ReferenceError: $rootScope is not defined`